# Give an example that converse need not be True?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

if  $H$ is  normal   subgroup  of $G$ and $G$ is finite ,the $\frac{G}{H}$  is finite . Give  an  example  that  converse  need not be True ?

As take  $G = S_n$ and $H= A_n$,then $\frac{G}{H}$  is finite but     Im  not able  to find  an example  that  converse need not be True

Pliz  help me

thanks u

Comment: Take any infinite group, direct sum it with a finite group, and mod out a copy of the infinite group. What do you get?

Comment: im not getting @T.Bongers...can u elaborate  more

Comment: No. Give it a try. Take $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. Can you think of any normal subgroup that you can quotient by and get a finite result? (And do you know the statement of the converse?)

Comment: Indeed, maybe the first thing for you to do, jasmine, is to state the converse, so that we'll all be trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I added the "group-theory" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take

$G = \Bbb Z, \tag 1$

and

$H = m\Bbb Z = \{ nm \mid n \in \Bbb Z \}; \tag 2$

then

$G/H = \Bbb Z /m \Bbb Z, \tag 3$

$\vert G /H \vert = \vert \Bbb Z / m \Bbb Z \vert = m, \tag 4$

but
$\vert G \vert = \vert \Bbb Z \vert = \infty. \tag 5$
.

Comment: thanks u  so much @ Rober lewis  sir

Comment: Glad to help out.  And thanks you for the "acceptance"!